# How to get parent node in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to display content into `RecyclerView`. In adapter class I use this code to pass selected node's key:

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("NewsKey",getRef(position).getKey());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This code passed key(blue arrow in screenshot), i also want to pass parent node(red arrow) as String. How can i get parent node and pass it in `putExtra` ?

[image: data]

Here is how i call my database:

```
private void setUpFirebase() {
    newsRecycler = findViewById(R.id.newsRecycler);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    newsRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NewsItem> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NewsItem>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("news"), NewsItem.class).build();

    newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(options, this);
    newsRecycler.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
}
```

Comment: How's your call to the firebase realtime database? Show us some code so we can guide you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getParent()` on the database reference "`getRef(position)`" in your case, and then put its key into the intent using `putExtra()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("NewsKey", getRef(position).getKey());
DatabaseReference parent = getRef(position).getParent();
if (parent != null)
    intent.putExtra("ParentKey", parent.getKey());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(ref.parent() != null) {
  val news = ref.parent().key()
}
```

For more information read [DatabaseReference#getParent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getParent())